# SQL query with R dbGetQuery()

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to wrap a query into a function but can't get it to work:
this works:

`dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT gene, expression FROM dataset WHERE gene = 'S100A9'")`

Now when I try to put this into a function to use it multiple times It does not work, I tried this:

```
SQL_gene_filter <- function(gene){
  dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT gene, expression FROM dataset WHERE gene = ", gene))
}
SQL_gene_filter('S100A9') --> Error: Unknown column 'S100A9' in 'where clause' [1054]
```

How would I put a query into a function in R sql?

Comment: FYI, it is really bad practice to `paste` _data_ into your query. You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

Comment: Doing so also fixes the issue with single-quotes, double-quotes, or whatever. Use this: `dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT gene, expression FROM dataset WHERE gene = ?", params=list(gene))`. No quotes required, never the risk of mis-quoting or confusing a string literal as an identifier (column name), never the risk of accidentally corrupting the query.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the advice. and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are that

- the code is specifying S100A9 as a column name but it should be specified as a character string
- `con` should be passed to the function.

Try

```
SQL_gene_filter <- function(con, gene) {
  dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT gene, expression FROM dataset WHERE gene = ?",
    params = list(gene))
}
SQL_gene_filter(con, "S100A9")
```

or

```
SQL_gene_filter <- function(con, gene) {
  sql <- sprintf("SELECT gene, expression FROM dataset WHERE gene = '%s'", gene)
  dbGetQuery(con, sql)
}
SQL_gene_filter(con, "S100A9")
```